# iPhone App to send location even when closed

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Basically, I've been learning Objective-C and how to develop for the iPhone over the past few months and have created a few basic applications. Now I've got an idea for an iPhone app that I'm interested in developing and I'm just looking for a bit of advice on wether it is actually possible. I'm looking to create an app that sends the iPhones location to my server every 15 minutes - even when the app hasn't been opened/isn't opened.

Is this possible? If it is, could you point me in the direction of some more info on this subject.

Thanks.

Comment: well your app can't do anything if it isn't running. As I understand it, iOS 4 will let you run apps in the background.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it allowed for location based app to transmite location data to remote server while working on the background ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319976/is-it-allowed-for-location-based-app-to-transmite-location-data-to-remote-server)

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your application as needing background location services. But this is available only in iOS 4, and user needs to allow location services for your app.

More info about multitasking can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5)
More info about getting users's location can find [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question could be a partial YES or a partial NO. Basically ur app can give location updates even when it is not opened ... and u can handle it to be sent to ur server whenever user location updates .. but it is not possible to send the location update on a time basis like every 15 minutes ..

If you want ur app to register for location updates in background mode, u have two options:-

1. send location update on significant location change (i.e. a location update is sent when user moves significantly such that the cell tower changes for the user ) in this case u have to use `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`  OR
2. send continous location updates by using  `startupdatingLocation` and in info.plist file declare background mode key for location updates (uses GPS)

and u have to handle `didUpdatetoLocation` for location updates in both cases and Ur app will be woken up in background as soon as a location update is recieved (beware of battery usage  in 2nd case)